# Close Activities TabHost launched on exit

Tags: android, android-activity, tabs, android-tabhost

I am working on an Android app that uses a TabHost.  I used the Google example to get it setup and it works great but I want to force the activities it launches to close when the user clicks exit.  Is there a way to do this?  All I've been able to find is examples on how to start a new activity, not close one that is already running.

Answer (score 1):

From your description, I believe that you want to call finish();

http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Activity.html#finish()

If this isn't what you were asking for, please expand on your question.

**Update**

Take a look at the intent flags.  The most used for me is FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP

http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/Intent.html#FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP

Comment: Sorry, I didn't word it good enough.  I am calling finish() in my TabHost activity, but the activities it starts on startup stay running in the background.  Is there anyway I can basically call finish() on each of the four activities my TabHost activity starts in the onDestroy() function in the TabHost activity?

Comment: You may want to look into the Intent Flags used for finishing and starting new Activities.  There are many kinds, so you'll want to read through them to figure out which one works best for you.  Link added to updated section of my answer

Answer (score 0):

Could you elaborate on why you want to kill these activities? The Android framework is happy doing resource management for you and killing activities as necessary to free up memory and processing power. Furthermore, forcing Android to relaunch an activity that would have ordinarily been loaded on instantiation every time the user clicks a particular tab in your tab host will cause latency.

Again, there may very well be a good reason why you want to do this, but could you please explain?

Comment: Not every time they click off a tab, only when the click the exit menu item I created.  Basically, when the program is exiting.  I want/need to do this because some database connections & cursors are being left open and I do not want that.